# inline comparison assign multiple variables

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to assign values to multiple variables while comparing inline (the ? operator) ?

Here is a dumbed down version of a non working code I wished would work

```
 var toto = true;
 var test0, test1;

 toto ? test0 = 'test0', test1 = 'test1' : null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never try to use the conditional operator as an `if` statement. It is designed to output a value.

```
something = condition ? value : other_value
```

You can use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign multiple values in one operation.

```js
var toto = true;
var test0, test1;

[test0, test1] = toto ? ['test0', 'test1'] : [null, null];
console.log({ test0, test1 });

toto = false;
[test0, test1] = toto ? ['test0', 'test1'] : [null, null];
console.log({ test0, test1 });
```